# Actual value of variable workspace_loc?

Tags: eclipse

How can I find out what actual path the variable workspace_loc points to? This is in the context of "External Tools Configurations".

Comment: It is just the path of the workspace you are currently using.

Comment: @greg-449 That's what it is supposed to be. But when I configure an ANT build using the button <Browse Workspace> and I choose a build file that is not in my workspace, but actually in my GIT repository, I still get a path based on workspace_loc, which is wrong, unless workspace_loc is not the path of the workspace.

Comment: If you mean something like ${workspace_loc:/project/file} then this is correct. The project is considered to be 'in' the workspace even though the actual files might be in GIT. The path is resolved as though there was a symbolic link from the workspace to the git location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ANT echo task:

assume that in the "External Tools Configurations" you defined basedir as:
`${workspace_loc:/com.my.tools}`

Then use the following in your ant build file:

`<echo message="${basedir}"/>`

Answer (score 2):

The actual variables values can be viewed in the project properties dialog using: Properties / Resource / Linked Resources / Path Variables. 
Expect to see a list of name/value pairs for ECLIPSE_HOME, PARENT_LOC, PROJECT_LOC and WORKSPACE_LOC.